# Pytest parametrize a test using a fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to better understand how to thoroughly unit test using `pytest` and came across a situation that I am not sure how to best approach.  I found similar questions here on SO about parameterizing fixtures themselves but I don't think that is what I want to do here. But maybe I am not fully understanding fixtures themselves?

Here is some sample code:

#### App Code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname: str, lname: str):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

    def upper_fullname(self):
        return f'{self.fname} {self.lname}'.upper()
```

#### Tests:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture_mm(conf={"fname": "mickey", "lname": "mouse"}):
    return Person(**conf)

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture_bb(conf={"fname": "bugs", "lname": "bunny"}):
    return Person(**conf)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'person, expected_result',
    [(fixture_mm, "MICKEY MOUSE"), (fixture_bb, "BUGS BUNNY")])
def test_uppernames(person, expected_result):
    assert person.upper_fullname() == expected_result
```

I would expect both of these tests to pass but instead I get an error message saying `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'upper_fullname'`.  What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because `fixture_mm` is a function. You need to call a function to get a value (`fixture_mm()`), but this is not going to work with fixtures.

But I don't think you even need fixtures here. You could make these into normal functions and use them like this:

```
def person_mm(conf={"fname": "mickey", "lname": "mouse"}):
    return Person(**conf)

def person_bb(conf={"fname": "bugs", "lname": "bunny"}):
    return Person(**conf)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'person, expected_result',
    [(person_mm(), "MICKEY MOUSE"), (person_bb(), "BUGS BUNNY")])
def test_uppernames(person, expected_result):
    assert person.upper_fullname() == expected_result
```

Caveat: since fixture parameters are evaluated at the module compile time, this might cause issues if the functions require some setup. On the other hand, if your functions are as simple as in this example, you could even save these objects as constants:

```
PERSON_MM = Person(fname="mickey", lname="mouse")
PERSON_BB = Person(fname="bugs", lname="bunny")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  But I still can't wrap my head around fixtures yet and would appreciate more information on the determination that "don't think you even need fixtures here".

Comment: @user9074332 The actual problem here is that fixtures have to go into the test method's parameters, which is not what you want. Generally, they are used either to setup/teardown test environment (e.g. create and cleanup a database) or to bring in some resources that would have to be constructed inside the test method otherwise (e.g. some complex object, like what you're trying to do here).